# Published site not using scripts and style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm pretty new to web development.

I'm working for some time on my web application.
When developing (Visual studio 2012) the site works as it should.
Until a week ago, every time I wanted to change my site, I've published my site and then copy the files to the server and everything works as it should.
About a week age, I've changed my UI, and ever since then, every time I'm publishing my site and copy the files, the site works but with no CSS and no Scripts.
I'm using relative paths (~/) and using rendering.

Any idea where to start and look for my problem?

My web Config:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
            <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
            <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /><section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" /></sectionGroup></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=*******************************;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HandShakeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/WristShakeModel.csdl|res://*/WristShakeModel.ssdl|res://*/WristShakeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****************************;;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="PayPalCoreSDK" publicKeyToken="5b4afc1ccaef40fb" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.0.0" newVersion="1.6.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

         --></runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
        <settings>

        </settings>
    </system.net><dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>

                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>

        <reporting enabled="true" />
    <openid>
            <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">

                </security>
                <behaviors>

                    <add     type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform,    DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty>
        </openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>

        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri></configuration>
```

In my route config:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ClientData", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Shaul

Comment: If you are using MVC then you have a file called "routeconfig.cs" in App_Start. Check that your css and script files are routed to the right folder.

Comment: I would suggest to try to use full paths - "domain/folder/file" and check if it works. Then you could detect what exactly to blame for this problem.

Comment: @levkaster - edit the question. And i'll try use full path.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, introduced authentication recently?

Comment: OK, I tried to read the css file directly from the browser. In the old version I can read it, in the new version I'm getting Forbidden - 403. I guess it has something to do with that.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you changed directory for these files or domain of your site? If so you should probably change access permissions for containing folder.

Comment: I've changed domain (I used to access with IP, now I'm using URL). But I have the old version side by side (on iis) with the new version, and the old is working as it should. How do I change permissions?

Comment: Actually I can access the CSS files directly from the browser, so u'm guessing It has nothing to do with permissions. Any other idea? Why does the website working on visual studio and not on published?

Comment: Check your authentication settings to make sure you aren't forcing authentication on the `/styles/` and `/scripts/` folder. If you're having trouble with this add your `web.config` to the question

Comment: Added web.config. I tried to copy the new website to the exact place of the old website (wwwroot) and it's the same result. no styling, no CSS. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Use F12 tools (in your browser) to find out if any references have failed

Comment: Are you using bundles (I see a reference to the System.Web.Optimization library)? If so, can you amend your question to show how you're specified them in BundleConfig.cs?

Answer (score 0):

To understand more the source of your problem you could try to:

-Run it on localhost first, to see if the problem comes from publishing or your have errors in your code that are blocking the scripts and CSS.

-Run it on different browsers and see if the results are the same.

Comment: I'm runing it on my local host (using visual studio) and it works as it should on all browsers.